# Inject DatabaseConfigProvider with macwire

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, macwire

I have tried to add **Slick** to my project

Create **RoomRepo** class

```
class RoomRepo @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]{/**...*/}
```

Inject it

```
class ChatEngine @Inject()(dbRoom: RoomRepo)(socketIO: SocketIO)(implicit mat: Materializer){/**...*/}
```

**ChatEngine** loaded with **macwire**

```
trait MyApplication extends BuiltInComponents
  with AssetsComponents
  with SocketIOComponents {
  lazy val dbConfigProvider = wire[DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]]
  lazy val dbRoom = wire[RoomRepo]
  lazy val chatEngine = wire[ChatEngine]
  lazy val engineIOController: EngineIOController = chatEngine.controller

  override lazy val router = {
    val prefix = "/"
    wire[_root_.router.Routes]
  }
  override lazy val httpFilters = Nil
}
```

And then I get this error:

> [error] /MyApplicationLoader.scala:31:59: type get is not a member of
>   object play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
>
> [error]   lazy val dbConfigProvider =
>   wire[DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]]
>
> [error]                                                           ^
>   [error] /MyApplicationLoader.scala:32:25: Cannot find a value of type:
>   [play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider]
>
> [error]   lazy val dbRoom = wire[RoomRepo]
>
> [error]                         ^ [error]
>   /MyApplicationLoader.scala:33:29: Cannot find a value of type:
>   [models.RoomRepo]
>
> [error]   lazy val chatEngine = wire[ChatEngine]

Answer (score 1):

[play-slick](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick) can be used to implement [compile-time dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/PlaySlick#Compile-time-dependency-injection) via MacWire by extending `SlickComponents`

> If you’re using compile-time DI, you can query the database config directly from the `SlickApi` using the `slickApi.dbConfig(DbName(name))` method. The `play.api.db.slick.SlickComponents` provide access to the `slickApi`.

like so

```
trait DatabaseComponents extends SlickComponents {
  implicit def ec: ExecutionContext
  lazy val dbConfig = slickApi.dbConfig[JdbcProfile](DbName("default"))
  lazy val roomRepo: RoomRepo = wire[RoomRepo]
}
```

Note `DbName("default")` refers to `default` database from `application.conf`, for example

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.profile="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

Modify `RoomRepo` to take `DatabaseConfig` instead of `DatabaseConfigProvider` like so

```
class RoomRepo(dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]))(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) ...
```

and mixin `DatabaseComponents` like so

```
trait MyApplication 
  extends BuiltInComponents
  with AssetsComponents
  with SocketIOComponents
  with DatabaseComponents {

  ...
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
}
```

Couple of more remarks:

- We probably should not mix `@Inject` with macwire because former is intended for runtime dependency injection whilst latter is for compile-time DI.
- The signature of `wire` is `def wire[T]: T` where `T` has to be a type resolved at compile time whilst `DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]` is a runtime value, therefore `wire[DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]]` will not compile.